# Grep text and put in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

As result of the `checkresiduals()` function from the `forecast` package I got this result:

```
#Result of checkresiduals() function
test <- "Q* = 4.5113, df = 4.6, p-value = 0.4237"
```

Now, my intention is to split this line of text with `grep()` or other functions into a data.frame (with three columns `Q*`, `df`, `p-value`), like in the example below:

```
    Q*         df       p-value
    4.5113     4.6      0.4237
```

Can anyone help me with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two alternative approaches:

1. Convert string into DCF format and use `read.dcf()`
2. "Computing on the language": Convert string into a valid R expression and use `parse()` / `eval()`

#### `read.dcf()`

Use the `read.dcf()` function after the string `test` is converted into DCF (Debian Control File) format.
(BTW, the `DESCRIPTION` file of each R package is in DCF format.)

```
library(magrittr) # piping used for readability
test %>% 
  stringr::str_replace_all("=", ":") %>%        # replace "=" by ":"
  stringr::str_replace_all(",\\s*", "\n") %>%   # replace ", " by line break
  textConnection() %>% 
  read.dcf(all = TRUE)
```

> ```
>      Q*  df  p-value 
> 1 4.5113 4.6   0.4237
> ```

All columns are of type character.

#### Computing on the language

```
library(magrittr) # piping used for readability
test %>%   
  stringr::str_replace_all("(\\S+) =", "`\\1` =") %>% 
  paste0("data.frame(", ., ", check.names = FALSE)") %>% 
  parse(text = .) %>% 
  eval()
```

> ```
>       Q*  df p-value
> 1 4.5113 4.6  0.4237
> ```

All columns are of type double.

```
test %>%   
  stringr::str_replace_all("(\\S+) =", "`\\1` =") %>%   
  paste0("data.frame(", ., ", check.names = FALSE)")
```

returns

```
"data.frame(`Q*` = 4.5113, `df` = 4.6, `p-value` = 0.4237, check.names = FALSE)"
```

which is then parsed into an expression and evaluated.

Note that all variable names are quoted to handle syntactically invalid variable names like `Q*` and `p-value`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `strsplit`.

```
tmp <- do.call(cbind, strsplit(strsplit(test, ", ")[[1]], " = "))
d <- setNames(data.frame(t(as.numeric(tmp[2, ]))), tmp[1, ])
#       Q*  df p-value
# 1 4.5113 4.6  0.4237
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(test) %>% 
    separate_rows(test, sep = ",\\s*") %>% 
    separate(test, into = c("v1", 'v2'), sep= " = ") %>% 
    deframe %>%
    as.list %>% 
    as_tibble
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  `Q*`   df    `p-value`
#  <chr>  <chr> <chr>    
#1 4.5113 4.6   0.4237
```

---

Also, it can modified into `JSON` and read it easily with `jsonlite`

```
library(jsonlite)
data.frame(fromJSON(paste0("{", gsub('([^0-9, ]+)(?: \\=)', '"\\1":', 
               test), "}")), check.names = FALSE) 
#       Q*  df p-value
#1 4.5113 4.6  0.4237
```